# Use UIAppearance styling except in modal view controllers?

Tags: ios5, uikit, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, modalviewcontroller

I customized the appearance of all my navigation bars by using the `UIAppearance` API introduced in iOS 5:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:titleTextAttributes];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:+2.f forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor lightTextColor]];
```

This works great for all my own navigation bars.

However, it *also styles all system-provided navigation bars,* such as when I modally display an `MFMailComposeViewController` (see screenshot below) or use the `ABPeoplePicker`.

Is it possible to define exceptions such as **“don’t use this appearance when shown modally”?**

[image: Inadvertently styled system navigation bar]

Answer (score 0):

take a look at appearanceWhenContainedIn option,  this allows you to select which viewcontroller class the appearance applies to